# How I can create correctly table structure `workers` or how can I create correctly Eloquent Relationships in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relationship

I have sample `workers` table structure:

[image: Workers table structure in Laravel project]

I have two type of workers: **company workers** and **company branches workers**. Type field can be only: **1** or **2**. 1 - is company worker and 2 - is branch worker. How Now I can't write correct relationships method to get user company type (branch or company). Or I must create 2 tables (company_workers_table and company_branch_workers_table) for correctly write eloquent relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a polymorphic relationship:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

You want to set up your workers with two columns instead of just the type one, lets call this relation `workplace`.  Your `workers` table would have `workplace_id` and `workplace_type` columns. The type columns holds the class of the related model (ie. `App/Company`) and your id column holds the ID of the related model, so the worker could be related to either a company or a company branch.

Your models will look something like this:

```
class Worker extends Model
{
    public function workplace()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    public function workers()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Worker', 'workplace');
    }
}

class Branch extends Model
{
    public function workers()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Worker', 'workplace');
    }
}
```

Comment: What will the table structure look like in the end? [Sample](https://repl.it/@OtabiekMansurov/Employees-database-design) ? @Jeff

Comment: @Otabek `workplace_id` is an unsigned integer. `workplace_type` is a string.  You can use `$table->morphs('workplace');` to create those columns automatically instead of doing each one.

Comment: When I add new worker to company return this error message `Add [user_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Employee].
`. How I can fix it? @Jeff

Comment: @Otabek that is an unrelated problem, you'll need a `$fillable` or `$guarded` property on your models. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment